# Android system storage shortage

Tags: internal-storage

Plz help me. My android 4.2.2 only has 1 app of 6.4 mb space. but my junk cleaning app says I have only 2% system space storage left. I cannot even download a single app from the playstore. plz somebody help me. I will be very thankful.
Thanks, Apon.

Comment: Go to Settings ->Storage.  What does this info say?

Comment: It says, Total space 0.98 GB, Available 1.40 MB, App(app and media content)-846 MB. Where I have only 1 app. Why? @Alex.S

Comment: And I'm also getting this notification 'Storage space running out'. @Alex.S

Comment: Maybe you have many photos,videos or music.

Comment: You think so? I have 49 Photos, 39 songs and 0 videos. Is that much? But I had a lot of movies on this device before. Not now. @Alex.S